# Selling and reselling NFTs with physical items

Tags: nft

As an example, let's say I have original Mona Lisa in my possession. I create some fancy digital NFT picture out of the original one and put it for sale on OpenSea. Whoever buys my NFT gets that original Mona Lisa picture with this NFT delivered to their home address.

Let's say Buyer A makes a purchase, NFT is transferred to him automatically and I will send original Mona Lisa by post to Buyers A home address.

So far so good, everything is straight forward.

Let's say Buyer A wants to resell that NFT and Buyer B buys it. How to ensure that Buyer A will send original Mona Lisa to Buyer B? There is too much space for scam from here on as Buyer A can easily disappear after that without sending original Mona Lisa to Buyer B.

What would be the best approach for reselling those kind of NFTs? How to keep track where original items are and if they are sent out from sellers or received by buyers?

Answer (score 3):

Well, for today the NFT isn’t really acknowledged as a right or property in terms of laws/global trade. In the future of Web3 and progress I believe this kind of trading will be enabled and acknowledged.

It’s possible to merge blockchain technologies with big companies like Amazon, EBay, etc…

Answer (score 3):

Create the **escrow contract**, which will hold the NFT and the funds until **both sides** confirm send/receive. But be ready to handle lots of offline stuff, as Seller has sent, but the Buyer assumes to not received. Or otherwise, you have to check the tracking codes, maybe the weights, etc.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking, and maybe 2 x price deposit that both buyer and seller needs to put in so it would be in their interest to send or confirm delivery.

Comment: This contract might be very problematic. You have to think about both parties interests to confirm/deny. In the real world you can sue in court, Here there is no centralised mediator.

Comment: @matank001 tenbits wants HABJAN to be the centralized mediator, I think - which won't work in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make sure that seller sends the physical item with the nft.

But, you can consider a marketplace like experience.

Build your own nft marketplace where NFTs are tied to physical objects. When a nft bought, price of it don't go directly to the seller, app take custody of the price and when buyer confirms that he received item, price goes to the seller. Just like online 2nd hand markets. Ofcourse there will be complaints as e-commerce have today.

You can't do it with the nft marketplaces out there, you should build your own.

This would be too challenging to develop and then it will require too much labor to operate. I can't think of any feasible option for this idea to work.